# Generate code with user's formatting in VS extension

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions

I have a Visual Studio extension that generates some code. How do I respect the user's formatting settings (like Tab vs Spaces, `this.` qualifier, etc) when generating it?

I know you can make a syntax tree in Roslyn but you still need to specify what exactly is in all of the whitespace. Is there a global way to apply this formatting or do we need to try and read all the individual settings?

If so, how would I read the tab vs space and `this.` prefix settings, respecting .EditorConfig files?

Currently my extension just builds a string assuming default settings, writes it to a file and adds it to the solution.

Comment: You can simply run the Roslyn formatter.

Comment: Found it! http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/68734D19.htm Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need the VisualStudioWorkspace object (which I assume you already have, otherwise take a look at Josh Varity's blog post [here](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/))
2. Generate your text and add it to the project using [AddDocument](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,475)
3. Call [GetOptionsAsync](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Document.cs,425) to get the set of options (.editorconfig, user settings, etc) that apply to this document
4. Call [Formatter.FormatAsync](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Formatting/Formatter.cs,80) passing in the optionset that was given to you by `GetOptionsAsync`
5. Update the formatted document by calling [WithDocumentText](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Solution.cs,763) on the solution.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with the MSBuildWorkspace? I've tried doing this but the Document that gets returned does not have any of the .editorconfig objects

Comment: We are working on adding support for this from the commandline compiler but it not implemented yet.  Here is an example of the work-in-progress https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/CodeStyle/Core/CodeFixes/FormattingCodeFixProvider.cs

Comment: I am sorry I am still so new to Roslyn to understand what is being shown to me in your WIP Link. I have a simple Command Line Tool that manually sets the Formatting Options (Gist Here: https://gist.github.com/aolszowka/7c7f374a5e1adf927d4113b2bec12fc3) but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get it to support .editorconfig is this just not possible? Having it also save the document would be useful instead of the StreamWriter hack I have.